# How to filter pod which are in running & completed status using field selector

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am applying below command to get the pods which are in running state:

```
oc get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running
```

I can get pods which are in running state. But I want to pods which are in Running and Completed state

How can we apply OR logic on status of the POD?

Answer (score 1):

--field-selector does not allow OR logic.

Try this using grep `kubectl get pod | grep "Running\|Completed"`

Or with awk `kubectl get po | awk '{ if ($3 == "Running" || $3 == "Completed") { print } }'`

Comment: If you want to also list all pods in the cluster that are **not** in the Running phase, you can run the command: `kubectl get pods -A --field-selector=status.phase!=Running `